# changed model DecimalField to Charfiled,and now form.is_valid() pass false in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I created a form with two `DecimalFields` and it worked fine. Next, I want to put a combo box in my view. So, I changed one `DecimalField` to `CharField`.

I deleted all the migration files and and rerun the `migrate` command. Now, the view is OK. But, when I select some value and submit the form it returns a form invalid error.

[image: after submit data]

### models.py

```
    PRODUCTS = (
    (0, 'Pedia Pro 250grm Pack'),
    (1, 'Pedia Pro 400grm Pack'),
    (2, 'Analene 400grm Pack'),
    (3, 'Analene 750grm Pack'),
    (4, 'Anchor 1 kg pack'),
    (5, 'Analene 750grm Pcak'),
    (6, 'Magarin '),
    (7, 'Magarin 500grm Pack'),
    (8, 'Anmun'),
    (9, 'Pedia 100grm Pack'),
)


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Key_Gen(models.Model):
    #key_beging_code =models.DecimalField('Brand_name +Pack_size' ,max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    key_beging_code =models.CharField("Product ",max_length=3, choices=PRODUCTS)
    key_quantity    =models.DecimalField("key Quantity" ,max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    key_code        =models.CharField('key Code' ,max_length=50 , unique=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField('public', default=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created',auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated',auto_now_add=True)



    class Meta:
        verbose_name='key_Gen'
        verbose_name_plural='keys_Gen'
        ordering = ['-date_created']


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.key_code)


    def adddate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.date_created = now()
        self.date_updated = now


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.key_code:
            self.key_code_temp =self.get_key_code(int(self.key_beging_code),int(self.key_quantity))
```

### forms.py

```
    #define form
class KeyGenarateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Key_Gen
        fields = ['key_beging_code', 'key_quantity']
        exclude = ('key_code','date_created', 'date_updated')
```

### views.py

```
@login_required
def key_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = KeyGenarateForm(data=request.POST)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
             #request.POST._mutable = True
             Key_Gen = form.save(commit=False)
             Key_Gen.save()
             return redirect('marcador_bookmark_user',username=request.user.username)
        else:
            print('form not valied')
    else:
        form = KeyGenarateForm()
        #print(form)
    context = {'form': form, 'create_key': True}
    return render(request, 'marcador/key_genarate_form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mismatch between ints and chars.

If your field is CharField, then make the choices char (the first element in each tuple), not int (e.g. '0' and not 0 or use letter).

Alternatively, change it to IntegerField.

BTW. You don't need both fields and exclude in your form.